# How to Bind multiple properties of one class to another using Entity Framework (EF) 4.1 Code First for use with Upshot.js?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, upshot

I have a scenario where I need to bind two properties from one class to another class using Entity Framework 4.1 Code-First. (For reference, this model is being consumed by Upshot.js for use in a single page application using Knockout.js 2.1)

Normally, I would have done something like the following:

```
    public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public Address HomeAddress { get; set; }
        public Address OfficeAddress { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Address
    {
        [Key]
        public int AddressId { get; set; }

        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    }
```

This allows HomeAddress and OfficeAddress to both reference an instance of the Address class.

*Please note this is not my real data model. It is for illustrative purposes only. In real life, I probably would have used an ICollection. Unfortunately, it is not feasible for this particular situation, and I do need to maintain multiple references from one class to another.*

In this particular scenario, it is also possible for a person to exist *without* any addresses defined. It is also possible for addresses to exist *without* a person. (As mentioned, this data model is just an example.)

While this compiles correctly, and I can even create and save data, upshot complains bitterly when it attempted to use this model.

It gives an (inner) exception like the following:

```
{"Unable to retrieve association information for association 'KnockoutTest.Models.Person_HomeAddress'. Only models that include foreign key information are supported. See Entity Framework documentation for details on creating models that include foreign key information."}
```

So... I attempted to set the Foreign Key information on the DbContext class like

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasOptional(m => m.HomeAddress);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasOptional(m => m.OfficeAddress);
}
```

No joy! This still gave me the same exception.

I am not sure how to set up the foreign key association so that multiple properties on one class can reference another class--at least not in a way that upshot will be pleased and stop complaining for a while.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to introduce scalar foreign key properties into your model class:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("HomeAddress")]
    public int? HomeAddressId { get; set; }
    public Address HomeAddress { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OfficeAddress")]
    public int? OfficeAddressId { get; set; } 
    public Address OfficeAddress { get; set; } 
}
```

The properties must be nullable (`int?`) because your relationships are *optional* (person can exist without addresses).